# Extract IP directly from Tcpdump Output

Tags: unix, awk, grep, tcpdump

I wanted to extract IP on a Tcpdump Command output.

```
tcpdump -nei eth0 and src 10.10.10.1
```

Sample Output of Above Command. As the output was very big I have posted it in below link.

```
https://pastebin.pl/view/3b6ab16d
```

Commands Which I tried

```
tcpdump -nei eth0 and src 10.10.10.1 | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"

tcpdump -nei eth0 and src 10.10.10.1 | awk '{sub(/^.*> /, "", $0); sub(/:.*$/,"", $0); sub(/\.[^\.][^\.]*$/,"",$0); print $0}'
```

I wanted the Output to be Like

```
140.345.12.45
140.345.12.45
140.345.12.45
140.345.12.45
140.345.12.45
140.345.12.45
```

Only the IP Address. Someone please help me.. T.I.A

Comment: use GNU grep: `tcpdump -nei eth0 and src 10.10.10.1 | grep -Po '> \K([^:]+)(?=\.[^:]+:)' `

Comment: Pipe it to: `grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'`

Comment: I tried both no output :(

Comment: @Am3Y instead of pastebin, better paste a few lines directly into the question. If there's too much, please try to reduce it and create a minimal sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @rethab I tried to reduce it but I thought a big output can help & will be very much clear how can we extract it :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. Tested and written in link https://ideone.com/ocWd19

```
awk '
match($0,/> ([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
}' Input_file
```